# Creating Event in Google calendar using api v3

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, sample

I have tryed this sample from google in c#.net but it is not working for me. any one have any sample for google calendar api v3

it is showing me the error as AuthenticatorFactory does not existing in current content.

I use the dll give by the google

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Util;
namespace Sample.Console
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Register the authenticator. The Client ID and secret have to be copied from the API Access
           // tab on the Google APIs Console.
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
        provider.ClientIdentifier = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
        provider.ClientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";
        AuthenticatorFactory.GetInstance().RegisterAuthenticator(
                () => new OAuth2Authenticator(provider, GetAuthentication));

        // Create the service. This will automatically call the previously registered authenticator.
        var service = new CalendarService();
    }
    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthentication(NativeApplicationClient arg)
    {
        // Get the auth URL:
        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue() });
        state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
        Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

        // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
        Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
        Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
        string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
        return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Auth Factory use OAuth2 authenticator object, google did not document this change very well...just remove the code with AuthenticatorFactory.GetInstance().... and replace with this line of code.  Everything else should stay the same.

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
```